# iOS 13 Simulator: reverseGeocodeLocation - [GEOAddressObject] [NSLocale currentLocale] failed for NSLocaleCountryCode@

Tags: swift, clgeocoder, reversegeocodelocation

Whenever I'm calling:

```
reverseGeocodeLocation(_ location: CLLocation, preferredLocale locale: Locale?, completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

I'm getting in the console:

```
[GEOAddressObject] [NSLocale currentLocale] failed for NSLocaleCountryCode@
```

I'm getting this on the **iOS 13 Simulator** (iPhone 6s), so I don't know if this also happens on a real device.
I've tested with `nil` and any `Locale` for `preferredLocale`, but it does not make any difference - I always get the failed-message.

Anyone else is experiencing this and found a solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was also getting this same error "failed for NSLocaleCountryCode@" on the simulator for all iPhone types. Running iOS 13.1.  I was able to solve it by going into Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> Region and updating the region from United States to Sweden (where I live).

Comment: Better late than never ;) Thank you - that worked! :)

Comment: Seems to work if you re-select the same region as well.  Thanks @JMBaker!

Comment: Modify "Edit Scheme" works as well, set App Region to e.g. Switzerland